# Reindex and fill out array depending on another array

Tags: php, arrays, default-value

I'm trying to create a tables with information from two arrays. Here are the two arrays:

First array, for table headers

```
Array
(
    [0] => Color
    [1] => Length
    [2] => Waist
)
```

Second array, the one that needs modification

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        [0] => green [1] => Color

    [1] => Array
        [0] => 23 [1] => Length
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        [0] => 23 [1] => Length

    [1] => Array
        [0] => 24 [1] => Waist 
)
```

Array needs to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        [0] => green [1] => Color

    [1] => Array
        [0] => 23 [1] => Length
    
    [2] => Array
        [0] => [1] => Waist 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        [0] => [1] => Color

    [1] => Array
        [0] => [1] => Length

    [2] => Array
        [0] => [1] => Waist  

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        [0] => [1] => Color

    [1] => Array
        [0] => 23 [1] => Length

    [2] => Array
        [0] => 24 [1] => Waist
```

So the point is that the keys in the first level needs to match the keys in the array that makes the table headers, where [1] one the second level has the same value as the table header. Any ideas?

---

After some feedback, an alternative acceptable output array structure would be:

```
array(
    array(
        'Color' => 'green',
        'Length' => 23,
        'Waist' => null
    ),
    array(
        'Color' => null,
        'Length' => null,
        'Waist' => null
    ),
    array(
        'Color' => null,
        'Length' => 23,
        'Waist' => 24
    )
)
```

Comment: It's tough to figure out your problem.  Do you have to reformat arrays?  Can you not change the script that generates them to give the arrays in the proper format?

Comment: Is the order of numeric keys important?

Comment: Why not `Array ( [Color] => green, [Length] => 23, [Waist] => 24 )` instead?  It's much more logical IMHO.  I comment instead of answer because it doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a complex array structure for an easy set of data.  Could your final array work better like this?

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'Color' => 'green',
        'Length' => 23,
        'Waist' => NULL
    ),
    array(
        'Color' => NULL,
        'Length' => NULL,
        'Waist' => NULL
    ),
    array(
        'Color' => NULL,
        'Length' => 23,
        'Waist' => 24
    )
);
```

If you're dead set on your structure, though, this should work:

```
function format_my_array($keys, $malformed) {
    foreach ($malformed as $key => $fragments) {
        $temp = array(
            'Color' => NULL,
            'Length' => NULL,
            'Waist' => NULL
        );
        foreach ($fragments as $fragment) {
            if (isset($fragment[1])) {
                switch($fragment[1]) {
                    case 'Length':
                        $temp['Length'] = $fragment[1];
                        break;
                    case 'Waist':
                        $temp['Waist'] = $fragment[1];
                        break;
                    default:
                        $temp['Color'] = $fragment[1];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        $malformed[$key] = array(
            array($temp['Color'], 'Color'),
            array($temp['Length'], 'Length'),
            array($temp['Waist'], 'Waist')
        );
    }
    return $malformed;
}
```

Comment: You're right, I'm going to work on the script that generates the array.

Comment: I thought I'd let you know that when I had looked over the code and added assossiative keys, I got the script working with a much cleaner code than I had before. As I'm pretty new with php I had totally forgotten how useful keynames can be. So, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generate the default values (once) as a re-usable array, then iterate your input data and overwrite the default values with each item's set of "attributes".

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uD9Pg)) ([PHP7.4+ Demo](https://3v4l.org/IpgJi))

```
$headers = ['Color', 'Length', 'Waist'];

$data = [
    [
        ['green', 'Color'],
        ['23', 'Length'],
    ],
    [],
    [
        ['23', 'Length'],
        ['24', 'Waist'],
    ],
];

$defaults = array_fill_keys($headers, null);
var_export(
    array_map(
        function($item) use($defaults) {
            return array_replace($defaults, array_column($item, 0, 1));
        },
        $data
    )
);
```